# Get element by class from selection of elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Example HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item active">Item 3</li>
    <li class="item">Item 4</li>
    <li class="item">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to get active element inside of `.nav`:

```
function someFunction() {
    var elements = $('.nav').find('.item');
    var active = elements.get('.active');
}
```

Of course that `.get` will not work. But this is example what I want to get. So I have variable containing elements and I want to get that `.active` element. I don't want `$('.nav').find('.item.active')`, because this is just an example, my code is much more complex and I want to work with that variable. Is it even possible in jQuery?

Comment: `.filter` not `.get`

Comment: Ooh yes, `filter` is that thing. Thanks! I have used it before, but it haven't come to my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the variable as jQuery element.

```
var elements = $('.nav').find('.item');
$(elements).filter('.active');
```

Comment: You don't need to use `$(elements)`. I was looking for that `filter`, so you have the correct answer.

Comment: We cant access as "elements.filter"  because filter is a jQuery function.Right??

Comment: You can use `elements.filter()`. I'm using it right now and it is working :)

Comment: Yeah its working in application. But when I tried it in Chrome console it doesn't work for me. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: That's weird, because `filter` is same function as `find`, while `filter` will goes through actual selection of elements, `find` will search for children elements in actual selection. I'm not very good in theory, but that's how it works.

Answer (score 1):

are you after the text of the active item? then target it directly

```
    var active = $('.nav .active').text();
```

if you want to display only the active item then:

```
$('.nav .item').css('display','none');
$('.nav .active').css('display','block');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.find()` method to get the active class element inside entire ul.

```
var activeObj = $(".nav").find(".active");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the active li inside ul directly by

```
var element = $('.nav li.active')
```